# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Bluetooth not working

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

Well I changed from windows 8.1 to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS yesterday, my first time ever using any Linux OS so am really really new to this terminal and all that, been trying to fix the Bluetooth from yesterday but to no avail, when I turn it on nothing happens at all, I want to turn it on to connect to my Bluetooth mouse. I can post a picture if it can help but I don't know how....

Comment: does not work. I have the same problem. My BT isn't able to find or be found by any BT device. Still, the BT icon is up and going. everything seems to be fine except it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Toshiba Portege R-700. 
My "solution" for the time being is, to go to 'System Settings' (should be on your launcher or on main menu on top left corner of Desktop), then click 'Bluetooth' and then repeatedly click the 'Bluetooth' switch to switch it On and Off until the Bluetooth symbol finally appears on the main menu toolbar.
From there you should be good to manage your Bluetooth connections.

I admit this is far from being optimal, but mean while until I find a real solution - this works for me!